# Why won't the gray box go inside the white box

Tags: css, html

I am trying to make a logo design business so i set up some HTML with some CSS to make a webpage that looks nice but along the way i realized that at the top the gray box won't go into the cyan box! I tried putting padding and doing a margin but it didn't work. Any tips? Here is the code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            #Logo{
            height:50px;
            width:250px;
            background-color:green;
            font-family:Algerian;
            color:white;
            text-align:center;
            }
            #Logo-border1{
            height:75px;
            width:275px;
            background-color:blue;
            }
            #Logo-border2{
            height:100px;
            width:300px;
            background-color:yellow;
            }
            #Logo-border3{
            height:125px;
            width:325px;
            background-color:red;
            }
            #Logo-border3:hover{        
            height:125px;
            width:325px;
            background-color:red;
            cursor:pointer;
            }
            #Header{
            padding:7px;    
            width:1554;
            height:175;
            background-color:cyan;
            }
            #Title{
            margin-right:100px;
            margin-bottom:0px;
            padding:3px;
            height:150;
            width:1150;
            background-color:gray;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body background="Images/Background.jpg">
        <table>
            <tr>
            <td>
            <div id=Header>
                <a style="color:white;text-decoration:none;" href="file:///C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/Website-Buy%20Items%20Cheap/Index.html" title="Logo Design">
                <div onClick=window.location=("file:///C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/Website-Buy%20Items%20Cheap/Index.html"); id="Logo-border3">
                <div id="Logo-border2">
                <div id="Logo-border1">
                <div id="Logo">
                    <h1>
                    <b>Logo Design</b>
                    </h1>
                </div></div></div></div></a>
            <td><div id="Title">hi</div></td>
            </div>
            </td>           
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

For all your broken HTML, I can tell you that `#Title` is in a *different `<td>` element* than `#Header`, therefore it will never be inside it.

Revise your HTML.

Also, units are required. Add `px` to all your unlabelled length numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something a bit more compact - [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/f5tLx/)

HTML

```
<div class='outerdiv2'>
<div class='outerdiv1'>
<div class='centerdiv'>Logo Design</div>
</div>
</div>
```

But I'm not really sure where you want the title.